# How do you comprehend "std: :forward is just syntactic sugar"? Is that true?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, perfect-forwarding, syntactic-sugar

How do you comprehend "std::forward is just syntactic sugar"? Is that true?  I would appreciate that if you could explain the related code below in detail.

As per the documentation(https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00416_source.html), 
here is the implementation of `std::forward`:

```
    /**
    *  @brief  Forward an lvalue.
    *  @return The parameter cast to the specified type.
    *
    *  This function is used to implement "perfect forwarding".
    */
   template<typename _Tp>
     constexpr _Tp&&
     forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type& __t) noexcept
     { return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t); }



  /**
    *  @brief  Forward an rvalue.
    *  @return The parameter cast to the specified type.
    *
    *  This function is used to implement "perfect forwarding".
    */
   template<typename _Tp>
     constexpr _Tp&&
     forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept
     {
       static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp>::value, "template argument"
                     " substituting _Tp is an lvalue reference type");
       return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t);
     }
    /**
    *  @brief  Convert a value to an rvalue.
    *  @param  __t  A thing of arbitrary type.
    *  @return The parameter cast to an rvalue-reference to allow moving it.
   */
   template<typename _Tp>
     constexpr typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&
     move(_Tp&& __t) noexcept
     { return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&>(__t); }
```

Comment: read scott meyers "effective modern c++" - goes into great depth on move and forward, they are just casts

Comment: "syntactic sugar" refers to a language-feature that doesn't add functionality but rather is there only to make the code easier to read and understand.  (It's probably a Mary Poppins reference, i.e. "a spoonful of sugar makes the medicine go down")

Comment: As you can see `std::forward` is a simple static cast.

Comment: What is your understanding of the term "[syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)"?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Glad to see you again! So is it true? I fully understand it is a type cast with your help yesterday. I have saw many such sayings indeed.

Comment: @JaMiT In computer science, syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express. It makes the language "sweeter" for human use: things can be expressed more clearly, more concisely, or in an alternative style that some may prefer.

Comment: Maybe this helps you understand it: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Yi4zGCFIHxZB5S1l

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thank you very much.  I almost understand the code aforementioned. I am confused that why `g(5)` invoke `void f(int &)` other than `void f(int &&)`. You see, `5` is an rvalue indeed. Could you please explain that in more detail?

Comment: Because a function parameter is always an l-value. It has a name, you can take its address and you can assign a value: https://wandbox.org/permlink/jaH1WObDtFWED1uP Therefor you have to cast it back to an r-value reference.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Bit of a reach to associate it with Mary Poppins specifically; sweetening something to make it more palatable was hardly the brainchild of Disney. As it happens, the first use of "syntactic sugar" (AFAICT) is from [a paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/819-f09/Landin64.pdf) from [January of '64](https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article/6/4/308/375725); Mary Poppins released in August of '64. You could just as easily (and as wrongly) claim the association went the other way. :-)

Comment: @ShadowRanger it's only a guess, I could be wrong.  Note that the Mary Poppins books were first published in 1934.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: [The song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Spoonful_of_Sugar) was written for the movie. Even if the books included a line like that as part of the dialogue, it was hardly a pop-culture sensation without the movie song. Sugar is awesome, syntactic sugar makes sense without any outside references.

Comment: @John That sounds like a good textbook definition. So why doubt that `std::forward` is syntactic sugar? It does nothing but control the value category of its argument, a task that could already be accomplished (in a less concise and less readable manner) via `static_cast`. I'd go as far as to suggest `std::forward` be a textbook example of syntactic sugar.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thank you so much. I fully understand it with your generous help. One more question, I can draw the conclusion that there is no way to get the address of an rvalue since what you told me. Am I right? Why doesn't it? Could you tell the reasons in detail?

Comment: @JaMiT Sorry, I am not a native speaker. I am afraid to misunderstand what you mean. If I understand what you mean correctly, you think `std::forward` is syntactic sugar. Am I right?

Comment: @ShadowRanger What do you mean by "Sugar is awesome, syntactic sugar makes sense **without any outside references** ."? Could you explain that in more detail?

Comment: @John That's a weak version of what I meant, but correct. More accurately, I am stating that `std::forward` is a great fit for the definition of "syntactic sugar", and I do not see why someone would question it.

Comment: @JaMit I see. Thank you for your generous help.

Comment: @John you should ask only one question. Stackoverflow is not a discussion platform. You can find your answers [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

Comment: And probably [here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers)

Comment: @John: It's an analogy. Sugar is sweet (nice to have) but nutritionally empty (not necessary). Syntactic sugar is just syntactic support to make a task easier (nice to have) for a task that you could have done without the suppor, but it would have been less pleasant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “std: :forward is just syntactic sugar”? Is that true?

Depends on what one means by "is just syntactic sugar".

> How do you comprehend “std: :forward is just syntactic sugar”?

I think that a correct and similar way to describe `std::forward` is that it is a very simple function template that can be implemented in standard C++.

In other words, providing `std::forward` in the standard library is not necessary in order for the programmer to do perfect forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the actual question is: "What does `std::forward` do and why is it necessary?"

`std::forward` can be called syntactic sugar for a `static_cast`. Usually (probably always) it doesn't do more than a cast. It casts the parameters of a function to a r-value resp. l-value reference and this is necessary in many cases, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int &) {
    std::cout << "L-value reference\n";
}

void f(int &&) {
    std::cout << "R-value reference\n";
}

template<typename T>
void g(T &&a) {
    f(a);
}

template<typename T>
void h(T &&a) {
    f(std::forward<T>(a));
}

template<typename T>
void i(T &&a) {
    f(static_cast<T&&>(a));
}

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    g(a);
    g(5);
    h(a);
    h(5);
    i(a);
    i(5);
}
```

prints

```
L-value reference
L-value reference
L-value reference
R-value reference
L-value reference
R-value reference
```

The function call `g(5)` calls `f(int &)`. That's usually not expected.

This happens because all function parameters are l-values. They have a name, one can take its address and assign a value, e.g.:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int &) {
    std::cout << " L-value reference\n";
}

void f(int &&) {
    std::cout << " R-value reference\n";
}

void j(int &&a) {
    std::cout << &a;
    a = 6;
    f(a);
}

void k(int &&a) {
    std::cout << &a;
    a = 6;
    f(std::forward<int>(a));
}

int main() {
    j(5);
    k(5);
}
```

prints

```
0x7ffc2db04ea8 L-value reference
0x7ffc2db04eac R-value reference
```

Comment: @John you should ask only one question. Stackoverflow is not a discussion platform. You can find your answers [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

Answer (score 1):

I understand the spirit of the question, however, I disagree with its premise.

Since std::forward can be implemented using the syntax of standard C++ it is not what is commonly referred to as "syntactic sugar"; that is, the implementation of std::forward required no novel syntax to be added to the language. "Syntactic sugar" is new syntax that the designer of a language has added to offer a less verbose way to express desired behavior that was nonetheless still expressible using the language as it was. (If it wasn't previously expressible then it is not syntactic sugar; it's a new language feature)

Actual syntactic sugar indeed *was* added in C++11. Range-based for loops are syntactic sugar.

Anyway, as for the spirit of the question, to understand the implementation of std::forward you need to understand two things

1. C++'s reference collapsing rules
2. Just the general idea that "forwarding references" are different than R-value references -- what Scott Meyers called "universal references".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. One more question, which statement is right when deducing `int a;f(a)`: "since a is an lvalue, so `int(T&&)` equate to `int(int& &&)`" or "to make the `T&&` equate to `int&`, so T should be `int&`"? I prefer the latter one.